# Error converting data type varchar to numeric when casting varchar(max) to decimal

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2, varchar

I'm trying to sum values from two strings. In order to do that I'm casting the strings in to decimals, add them up and then cast it back to string for the output. Also using max to avoid duplication entries. 
I have the following line in my SP:

`Cast( Max(CASE WHEN QuestionID = 261 THEN CAST(Answer AS decimal) ELSE '' END) + Max(CASE WHEN QuestionID = 260 THEN CAST(Answer AS decimal) ELSE '' END) AS varchar) as Total`

The Answer field is varchar(max) and default value is ''.
 The problem is that I'm getting the error message: Error converting data type varchar to numeric

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The part that is failing is the inner case:

```
CASE WHEN QuestionID = 261
     THEN CAST(Answer AS decimal)
     ELSE '' END
```

A `CASE` expression (e.g.above) must return one datatype only.  In this case, it cannot both return a decimal and a varchar (empty string ''). Due to [type precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx) the result from either branch is cast to a decimal. If **ANY** row has `QuestionID != 261`, it will try to cast that `''` into decimal, and **bam** - your error.

You need this:

```
Cast( Max(CASE WHEN QuestionID IN (261,260) AND ISNUMERIC(ANSWER) = 1
               THEN CAST(Answer AS decimal)
               ELSE 0 END)
   AS varchar) as Total
```

Comment: Still getting the error message. I found a way to do it, It's not most elegant one, but does the job: ` Cast(Max(CASE WHEN QuestionID = 261 THEN CAST(Case When Answer = '' Then 0 Else CAST(Answer as decimal(9,2)) End as decimal(9,2))End ) + 
                      Max(CASE WHEN QuestionID = 260 THEN CAST(Case When Answer = '' Then 0 Else CAST(Answer as decimal(9,2)) End as decimal(9,2))End )AS varchar(Max)) as Total`

Comment: What does your query look like now? Have you replaced the `''`'s with 0's?

Comment: I got another error message when I try to run it:  Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.

Comment: Yes, that works, but  it shows the result with no decimal spaces and I need them also.Even so, way smaller than mine :), thanks

Comment: You merely need to cast the answer properly to decimal(m,n), using an appropriate value, e.g. decimal(12,4).

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit more readable..

`Cast(Max(CASE WHEN QuestionID = 261 THEN CAST(Case When Answer = '' Then 0 Else CAST(Answer as decimal(9,2)) End as decimal(9,2))End ) + 
                      Max(CASE WHEN QuestionID = 260 THEN CAST(Case When Answer = '' Then 0 Else CAST(Answer as decimal(9,2)) End as decimal(9,2))End )AS varchar(Max)) as Total`